# Regex to match rails get index urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match only index urls (with or without parameters) in rails.

The following three match what I expect:

```
regex = /^http:\/\/localhost:3000\/v2\/manufacturers\/?(\S+)?$/
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers?enabled=true')
#=> true
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/')
#=> true
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers')
#=> true
```

I expect the regex not to match these:

```
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/1')
#=> true
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/123')
#=> true
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/1?enabled=true')
#=> true
```

Edit:

I'm so sorry but I forgot to mention that it should match:

```
regex.match?('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/1/models')
```

as it is a valid index url

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\Ahttp:\/\/localhost:3000\/v2\/manufacturers(?:\/?(?:\?\S+)?|\/1\/models\/?)?\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/xpgYXgUJdy)

**Pattern details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `http:\/\/localhost:3000\/v2\/manufacturers` - a `http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers` string
- `(?:\/?(?:\?\S+)?|\/1\/models)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\/?` - an optional `/` char
  - `(?:\?\S+)?` - an optional sequence of `?` and 1+ non-whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `\/1\/models\/?` - `/1/models` string and an optional `/` at the end
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: If that `/?` should be matched, the non-capturing group may be changed to [`(?:\/|\/?\?\S+)?`](http://rubular.com/r/PMNUrtO1m3). Or OP might use [`\Ahttp:\/\/localhost:3000\/v2\/manufacturers\/?(?:\?\S+)?\z`](http://rubular.com/r/GKk13h7Ze3).

Comment: +1 for explanation and fiddle.
I added another valid case, if you could please cover that I'll accept the answer. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @fabriciofreitag I edited the answer to address all the new test cases. BTW, in RoR, you should use `\A` and `\z` anchors rather than `^` and `$` to match start and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the end of your regex from:

```
\/?(\S+)?$/
```

to:

```
\/?(?:\?\S+|\d+\/\S+)?$
```

That would create an optional noncapturing group `(?:\?\S+|\d+\/\S+)?`.

- Match `\?\S+` for your questionmark and non whitespace chars
- or `|`
- Match `\d+\/\S+`for the added case of `1/models`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XIGu0e/2)

Comment: A better approach.

Comment: Downvoted by @WiktorStribiżew with no reason. © All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` character makes the character optional

This works for me: `http:\/\/localhost:3000\/v2\/manufacturers?\/?`

> r = /http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers?/?$/
>
> r.match('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/1?enabled=true')
>   => nil
>
> r.match('http://localhost:3000/v2/manufacturers/1')
>   => nil